# Load Steps into Console?

Tags: cucumber, calabash, calabash-android

Is it possible to load the step definitions I have defined into the calabash-android console?

I would like to be able to use them when navigating the app within the console.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No from the console you can not run a single step definition.
But you can start execution of a test at a specific line appending parameter to the call to start your test

```
:<linenumber>
```

This will start execution of your feature file from that specific line and it will run from there to the end of the file.

So while it is not what you are looking for at least it is something.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I do know about executing a test at a specific line number. It would just be nice to be able to test steps in the console. sigh.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try `step('<step_name>')` method?
To be honest I'm not sure if this will work. I know it's working insinde Ruby methods and step definitions - I wanted to post a comment but I can't with 28 points of reputation ;)
You can also try making ruby methods with code from within the step definition:

```
Then /^I do something$/ do
  some code
  goes here
end

def do_something
  some code
  goes here
  # same code as in step definition
end
```

or just use `step method`:

```
def do_something
  step('I do something')
end
```

and then call it in a calabash console (I prefer using `binding.pry` inside some script rather than calling "pure" calabash-console - it makes me sure that I will have all needed methods included).